# Facebook App webhooks: Callback URL & Page tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, webhooks

Hi I am held up with couple of problems from past couple of days. Please can anyone help me out.

1. I want to get the real time updates of my facebook page. I created an App & added it as the Page tab but I am getting the below message when i clicked the tab in the facebook page.

> Method Not Allowed Error 405

2. Also when subscribing the real time updates/webhooks in facebook, is it necessary to give domain name/callback.php in callback URL? I mean I just want to test the flow right now and don't want to buy a domain for testing.
3. Also when i am putting this https://graph.facebook.com//subscriptions?access_token=****
   I am just getting

   {
      "data": [

   ]
   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Subscribing to a page for updates is not done by installing it as a page tab app any more, but by making a POST request to `/page/subscriptions`

---

`Method Not Allowed` means your server did not accept a POST request to the URL. Facebook makes a POST request to load an app into a page tab. If you tried to use that same URL as your webhook callback URL, you need it to accept POST requests as well.

---

2. Of course the URL needs to be reachable from the outside, otherwise Facebook could not make a POST request to it. As far as I know Facebook does not accept IP addresses, you need to use a domain name. Plus, webhooks now require an HTTPS URL, with a valid SSL certificate. Self-signed certificates are not accepted, so you practically have no other choice than to use a "real" domain, dyndns or something won't work.
3. That's because you have not actually subscribed your app for updates of the page. Again, that has nothing to do any more with page tabs, it needs a POST request to that endpoint.

Comment: 1. Can you let me know how to make a POST request to /page/subscriptions. And do we need to mention the code in callback endpoint php script or its a one time thing?

Comment: 2. Is there any free webhosting site where i can put my endpoint php?

Any particular tutorial you can direct me to would be really beneficial for me. This is the first time i am extracting real time data from facebook. :(

Comment: 1. Like you would make any other API POST request. You did not specify any platform/sdk/language you are using - so please start by looking that up in the respective documentation. 2. That you should go research yourself, it is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: I am using facebook-php-sdk-v4. I am running short of time. Can you give me a brief solution of how to make API POST request?

Comment: I went to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ chose my App then select the facebook page. Then give the POST request to /page_id/subscribed_apps
Now it gave success=True. I hope i am doing it correctly.

Comment: @gagan facing some same issues here.Did your's work?